# Wordpress custom permalink issue

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have created custom post_type_link in wordpress. It works very well. But when I open a single post of that post type it doesn't work, it redirects to 404 page. Any suggestions please?

```
function tpcl_custom_post_types() {
register_post_type( 'tpcl_mtr',
    array(
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tpclmtr' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    )
);

register_post_type( 'tpcl_utr',
    array(
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tpclutr' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    )
);
add_action( 'init', 'tpcl_custom_post_types' );


function tpcl_post_permalinks( $post_link, $post ) {
$tpcl_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_tpcl_post_tmeta', true );
$type_name = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
if ( 'tpcl_mtr' === $post->post_type ) {
    $p_type = str_replace( $type_name, 'mtr', $type_name );
    $permalink = home_url( 'tpcl/'. $tpcl_meta . '/' . $p_type . '/' . $post->post_name );
} elseif ( 'tpcl_utr' === $post->post_type ){
    $p_type = str_replace( $type_name, 'utr', $type_name );
    $permalink = home_url( 'tpcl/'. $tpcl_meta . '/' . $p_type . '/' );
} else{
    $permalink = $post_link;
}
return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'tpcl_post_permalinks', 1, 3);
```

Comment: When you register the post type using `register_post_type` there are some arguments that might be relevant. Can you share the code that does that?

Comment: @IT goldman, I have updated my code. Please check and give a solution please.